# Understanding ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type) Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, object, casting

I don't quite understand the point of this method.

It converts a ValueProviderResult to an Object.. but the Method takes a parameter of *Type* that its supposed to convert to. So what is the point? or why does it require *Type* argument if it will always just return a type of object?

Here is an working example:
You can see that after I convert it, I still have to cast it to its proper type.

```
RequestTypeEnum requestType = (RequestTypeEnum)(object)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(requestTypePropertyName).ConvertTo(typeof(RequestTypeEnum));
```

Comment: the underlying object will be an instance of the type entered.

Comment: You can always create a generic extension method if you want to work with concrete types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying object will be an instance of the Type entered.

The point of the method

[ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo Method (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.valueproviderresult.convertto(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(System.Type))

> Converts the value that is encapsulated by this result to the
>   specified type.

You can always create a generic extension method if you want to work with concrete types

```
///<summary>
/// Converts the value that is encapsulated by this result to the specified type.
///</summary>
public static class ValueProviderResultExtension {
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this ValueProviderResult valueProvider) {
        return (T) valueProvider.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Which is then used like

```
RequestTypeEnum requestType = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(requestTypePropertyName).ConvertTo<RequestTypeEnum>();
```

Comment: Awesome answer! thanks :) do you know why they didn't implement it like this to begin with? It makes more sense than converting to an object that has to be casted

Comment: What is the equivalent of this in .Net Core?